# not getting output after running server

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

i have created a simple program of jsp. there was no error in the program. however when i am running the apache tomcat serverv7.0 in eclipse it displays :
404 resource not available.
can someone please tell me why this is happening? I have created program in eclipse mars. my code is below:
index.jsp\

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="process.jsp">  
No1:<input type="text" name="n1" /><br/><br/>  
No1:<input type="text" name="n2" /><br/><br/>  
<input type="submit" value="divide"/>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

process.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" %>  
<%  

String num1=request.getParameter("n1");  
String num2=request.getParameter("n2");  

int a=Integer.parseInt(num1);  
int b=Integer.parseInt(num2);  
int c=a/b;  
out.print("division of numbers is: "+c);  

%>  
</body>
</html>
```

error.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>  

<h3>Sorry an exception occured!</h3>  

Exception is: <%= exception %>  
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>first</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: please paste the stacktrace

Comment: would you please post the project files tree? it's not about code,

Comment: Under which folder of eclipse is your index.jsp?

Comment: its inside first/webcontent  where first is the name of my project